# How to do tests with JPA and JUnit on differents persistence units?

Tags: java, database, jpa, junit, persistence

I am very new using JUnit. I want to test some classes that implements JPA. But, I have two databases, one for testing and other for development.

Normally, the testing db is clean. I test inserts, updates, delets, so and so, but any time I have to switch the db connection to testing db.

How can I have two persistence units: one for testing and other for development?

Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either have two different persistence units in your persistence.xml file, or you can have one, and create your EntityManagerFactory passing in a properties map that override the database parameters.

Your entities/mappings can be the same for both.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use 2 sets of spring config files or configuration classes and reference the test configuration files in the unit tests.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I'm not using Spring.